# Dropping column in dataframe with assignment not workng in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes (df_train and df_test) containing a column ('Date') that I want to drop.

As far as I understood, I could do it in two ways, i.e. either by using inplace or by assigning the dataframe to itself, like:

```
if 'Date' in df_train.columns:
    df_train.drop(['Date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

OR

```
if 'Date' in df_train.columns:
    df_train = df_train.drop(['Date'], axis=1)
```

Both the methods work **on the single dataframe**, but the former way should be more memory friendly, since with the assignent a copy of the dataframe is created.

The weird thing is, I have to do it for both the dataframes, so I tried to do the same within a loop:

```
for data in [df_train, df_test]:
    if 'Date' in data.columns:
        data.drop(['Date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

and

```
for data in [df_train, df_test]:
    if 'Date' in data.columns:
        data = data.drop(['Date'], axis=1)
```

and the weird thing is that, in this case, only the first ways (using inplace) works. If I use the second way, the 'Date' columns aren't dropped.
Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because iterating through the list and changing what's in the list doesn't actually change the actual list of dataframes because it only changes the iterators, so you should try:

```
lst = []
for data in [df_train, df_test]:
    if 'Date' in data.columns:
        lst.append(data.drop(['Date'], axis=1))
print(lst)
```

Now `lst` contains all the dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use a `list comprehension`:

```
res = [data.drop(['Date'], axis=1) for data in [df_train, df_test] if 'Date' in data.columns]
```

Here, you will get a copy of both dataframes after columns are dropped.